# Flags for `systemctl reboot`?

Tags: reboot, systemctl

I'm having trouble finding the `systemd` unit file for `reboot`. I would like to explore the options I can pass to `sudo systemctl reboot`, but am having trouble finding documentation or implementation to search.

What flags can I pass to `sudo systemctl reboot`?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by finding a unit file? Rebooting isn’t a _unit_, though some targets are involved.

Comment: I wanted a delay with granularity of a second or two, something that `shutdown -r  +someminutes` doesn't offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ man systemctl` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
Hit `/` and type `^ +reboot` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
*(There is a single   between ^ and +)*

`$ man 2 reboot` is mentioned in there.